# AMP Audio: Track Play/Pause/Complete and Capture in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html, amp-analytics

I am working with the `amp-audio` component for a project, and need to be able to set up tags and triggers in Google Tag Manager track when the user plays/pauses the audio, and when the audio completes. From the [documentation for `amp-audio`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-audio/?format=websites#analytics), it claims that I can utilize the Audio Play and Pause triggers to track the events via `amp-analytics`. However, this does not work to trigger any analytics. Further, the [`amp-analytics` documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-analytics/#triggers) only lists `video-*` for media-related triggers, with *no* reference whatsoever anywhere on the page to anything related to `amp-audio`. This conflict of documentation is not only confusing, but frustrating since there's no way to tell which is accurate, if either.

Code snippets and trigger configuration (taken straight from the `amp-audio` documentation, updated with my own `id`s), which does *not* work:

```
<amp-audio id="my-amp-audio-player" controlsList="nodownload" height="50" width="auto">
  ...
</amp-audio>
```

...and...

```
"triggers": {
  "audioPlay": {
    "on": "audio-play",
    "request": "event",
    "selector": "#my-amp-audio-player"
  },
  "audioPause": {
    "on": "audio-pause",
    "request": "event",
    "selector": "#my-amp-audio-player"
  }
}
```

As a workaround, I've also tried to include and use custom JS via the `amp-script` component. Using this with `amp-audio` has proven fruitless, and I've also tried to use a straight-up `audio` tag in place of `amp-audio`. Using the pure `audio` tag gives me the ability to target the audio player and capture `play`, `pause`, and `ended` events...however, trying to do *anything* that would result in a successful AMP trigger ends up throwing the "terminated due to illegal mutation" error as documented in the [`amp-script` documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/?format=websites#errors).

Code snippets for a click event trigger set up in Google Tag Manager:

**Markup:**

```
<amp-script layout="container" src="/static-assets/audio.js">
  <audio id="my-amp-audio-player" controls controlsList="nodownload" height="50" width="auto">
    ...
  </audio>
  <button id="btn-audio-play-trigger">Play Trigger</button>
  <button id="btn-audio-pause-trigger">Pause Trigger</button>
</amp-script>
```

**JS:**

```
const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('my-amp-audio-player')
audioPlayer.addEventListener('play', () => {
  // Below (and other uses of this) results in illegal mutation error (if an AMP component)
  // or something like 'TypeError: document.getElementById(...).click is not a function'
  // when using a <button> element
  document.getElementById('btn-audio-play-trigger').click()
})
audioPlayer.addEventListener('pause', () => {
  document.getElementById('btn-audio-pause-trigger').click()
})
audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  // TODO: Implement functionality as needed
})
```

---

**Current Status:**

No matter which implementation or combination of uses I implement, nothing I've tried has been able to successfully trigger and catch an `amp-audio` or `audio` event that Tag Manager can catch and log. Any advice, insight, or direction is appreciated!